# What does Delphine say to Lorraine?

Tags: dialogue, atomic-blonde

In *Atomic Blonde* Lorraine and Delphine are in Lorraine's hotel room. Delphine says something along the lines of "I need to tell you something about your friend Percival..." but Lorraine cuts her off. Lorraine turns on the radio so that (I presume) any bugs in the room can't hear what Delphine whispers in Lorraine's ear. The audience doesn't hear and it isn't revealed later in the movie as far as I can tell.

What does Delphine whisper into Lorraine's ear about Percival?

Comment: I'm actually going to see the movie again tonight and might come back to edit this question with more details. I'm going to specifically pay attention to this scene.

Comment: I'm thinking what she says might have something to do with Delphine knowing Percival but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have proof... but I believe Delphaine told Lorraine

> about her photographs of Percival meeting the Soviet to make the deal for the list.

I'm basing this partly on how I interpreted some of the 'flashback' type scenes, and partly on pacing of the plot.

Comment: Can you go a little more into detail about how you interpreted the 'flashback' type scenes and the pacing of the plot to draw that conclusion?

Comment: Not sure I agree with that or else the discovery of the envelope left in the dark room wouldn't have been all that much of a surprise to her.  If she knew it was there, she would have been more direct to it and not take her time to see all the photos around and then notice an envelope with her name on it.

Comment: @ggiaquin That seems to sink a large hole in my theory... which leaves me somewhat at a loss.  I was so sure that's what was discussed (as I was leaving the theater)... but now...  I may need to go see it again: see if there are more clues.

Comment: Don't we hear a recording of what she said late in the movie? The actual words escape me, though.

Comment: @matt_black If you're talking about the "You look different when you tell the truth" recording, that doesn't say anything we hadn't directly heard.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Delphine tells Lorraine that she (Delphine) was following Lorraine for Percival. Lorraine was no surprised or suspicious of Delphine when she found the wire in her coat. Instead, she said Percival had set them both up.